# Should I make all my decisions standing up?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, study-cognitive-scienc

Does the brain work better:

...sitting rather than lying down.

...standing rather than sitting.

...walking rather than standing.

I have found this research, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3973903/, The effect of body posture on cognitive performance: a question of sleep quality, but it does not speak to decision making. The same for http://razlab.mcgill.ca/docs/Body_posture_alters_human_resting_state.pdf.

Can you offer examples of studies of cognitive function vs. body position.

Comment: The N-back task used in Muehlhan et al. (2014) you cite is a working memory task, which is 'cognitive function' as you ask for at the end of your question. But, from the rest of your question I understand you are interested in the impact of different body postures on higher-level decision making.

Comment: @StevenJeuris  Oh, I don't know ...I didn't know working memory is not a 'higher' function.

Comment: That's not what I said... I am implying (and maybe should have made it explicit) that your question is not _"Can you offer examples of studies of cognitive function vs. body position."_ If it is, you are answering it yourself by linking to Muehlhan et al. (2014).